# PHP str_replace is replacing but clearing the rest of the text

Tags: php, str-replace

I am using str_replace to replace a substring of a string however, the replacing happens but the rest of the text is disappearing.

Example of $log_text is **%%clinicid=1%% clinic we have five rooms.**

```
function strafter($string, $substring) {
  $pos = strpos($string, $substring);
  if ($pos === false)
   return $string;
  else  
   return(substr($string, $pos+strlen($substring)));
}

$log_text = '%%clinicid=1%% clinic has <b>5</b> rooms.';

if (strpos($log_text, '%%clinicid=') !== false) {
    $clinicid = strafter($log_text,'%%clinicid='); 
    $clean_clinicid = str_replace('%%','',$clinicid);
    $clinicname = $db->single("SELECT clinic_name FROM dg_clinics WHERE id = :id", array("id"=>"$clean_clinicid"));

    $clinic_id_string = '%%clinicid='.$clinicid;

    $log_text = str_replace($clinic_id_string,$clinicname,$log_text);

}
```

The above code gives

> Aaa

only not the full text, instead of

> Aaa clinic has **5** rooms.

Where am I doing wrong?

PS. if I use `%%clinicid=1%%` it works perfectly but with a string it doesn't work.

Comment: What is an example of `$log_text` and `$clinicid`?

Comment: Try to include a full, working example of your problem.  I should be able to execute it and see your output.

Comment: @adams try to get your result there - https://eval.in/582124

Comment: I've tried your code but it didn't work, I have updated and put my full code. @splash58

Comment: Your code works as posted. How are you trying to use the `$clean_clinicid` string? I can imagine for example, that if you tried to use it in ah HTML attribute string without quotes, the result would be only the first word before whitespace would be present.  By that I mean something like `"<input value=$clean_clinicid>"` instead of `value='$clean_clinicid'` with quotes.

Comment: I am using it in an array list to populate data for jquery dataTable @MichaelBerkowski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use preg_match to get clinic id and patern for str_replace

```
$log_text = '%%clinicid=1%% clinic has <b>5</b> rooms.';

if (preg_match('/%%clinicid=(\d)%%/', $log_text, $m) !== false) {
   $clean_clinicid = $m[1] ."\n";
   $clinicname = $db->single("SELECT clinic_name FROM dg_clinics WHERE id = :id", array("id"=>"$clean_clinicid"));
   $log_text = str_replace($m[0],$clinicname,$log_text);
}
echo $log_text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should echo out what you get for your http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
echo "$clinic_id_string<br>";
echo "$clinicname<br>";
echo "$log_text<br>";
```

that should give you a hint of why it doesnt work.